# cTAKES 4, custom dictionary, CAS Visual Debugger (CVD) and AggregatePlaintextFastUMLSProcessor.xml

Tags: ctakes

I was able to install cTAKES 4 with the following documentation https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CTAKES/cTAKES+4.0+-+Fast+Dictionary+Lookup

On my Windows 10 machine I run the CAS Visual Debugger (CVD) application via the following command:

```
bin\runctakesCVD.bat desc\ctakes-clinical-pipeline\desc\analysis_engine\AggregatePlaintextFastUMLSProcessor.xml
```

Based on the following example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4aOnafv-NQs I created the custom ICD10 dictionary and added it to my cTAKES 4 instance(with Dictionary Creator GUI).

Right now I don't understand how to run CAS Visual Debugger (CVD) with this new dictionary in order to be able to detect ICD10 codes in the text.

Could you please instruct me how it can be done?

Comment: I used the instructions in the video you mentioned, I got 2 files icd10.properties & icd10.script. I dont know how to use them in "cTAKES Piper File Submitter". any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the piper file in the following [github link](https://github.com/GoTeamEpsilon/ctakes-rest-service/blob/master/ctakes-web-rest/src/main/resources/pipers/DictionarySubPipe.piper)

The last line in the piper - `add DefaultJCasTermAnnotator LookupXml=org/apache/ctakes/dictionary/lookup/fast/customDictionary.xml` which has the `LookupXml` attribute that helps us to define the custom dictionary.

Comment: I used the instructions in the video you mentioned, I got 2 files icd10.properties & icd10.script. I dont know how to use them in "cTAKES Piper File Submitter". any advice?